# Django - LANGUAGE_CODE - 'en-IN' does not work, but 'hi-IN' works

Tags: django, localization, separator

**Django version 2.2 and 3.0**

**Purpose**: I would like to display numbers in India locale format. For e.g. 1000000 should be displayed as 10,00,000

**Action**
To do this, I went to     `settings.py`    and made the following changes:

1. `LANGUAGE_CODE = 'IN'`     - date and time was displayed in Indonesian format but grouping of numbers were **correct**
2. `LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-IN'`     - date and time was displayed properly but grouping of numbers were **incorrect**
3. `LANGUAGE_CODE = 'hi-IN'`     - date and time had Hindi language display but grouping of numbers were **correct**

**What I want**

`LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-IN'`     to display date and time properly and also do number grouping

My **settings.py** file :

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-IN' 
TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR = True
NUMBER_GROUPING = (3,2, 0)
USE_TZ = True
```

I had a look at [Number Grouping](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-NUMBER_GROUPING) which actually talked about this but I believe documentation is misleading. For starters they have put language code as **en_IN** which doesn't work.

Let me know if any additional information needed.

Comment: I solved this problem using my own [format.py](https://kappataumu.com/articles/exploring-django-format-localization-settings.html) and [github](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/conf/locale/en/formats.py)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a folder under my app called formats.

I placed a file called **formats.py** where I added the following :

```
NUMBER_GROUPING = (3,2,0)
THOUSAND_SEPARATOR = ','
DECIMAL_SEPARATOR = '.'
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ['%d-%m-%Y']
```